# Docker: daemon is not running, how to start daemon on windows 11?

Tags: windows, docker, daemon

Suddenly Docker daemon is stopped on windows 11.

```
> docker ps
error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/json": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

What may cause the daemon to stop? how to restart it?